# Stop for loop Cypress Javascript

Tags: javascript, cypress

I wrote this script On Cypress but if '.detailArticle' is found in '#fndRow1' the for loop continous execution. I want to break for loop when '.detailArticle' is found

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        cy.get('#fndRow-' + (i - 1))
          .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
          .click();
      }
      cy.get('#fndRow-' + i)
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .click();
      cy.get('.infosArticleBtn')
        .click()
        .then(() => {
          cy.get('.infosArticleBtn').then(() => {
            cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
              if ($body.find('.detailArticle).length > 0) {
                cy.get('.detailArticle').click();
              }
              cy.log("article not found");
            });
          });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't call Cypress commands inside a loop and also break early.

The commands happen on the queue asynchronously from the for loop, so you already have 5 iterations set up before the queue starts to run.

What you have is actually an **anti-pattern for testing**, instead you should know the page data and select elements appropriately without having to loop and "discover" values during the test.

Answer (score 0):

To break the for loop when .detailArticle is found, you can add a condition to check if it exists inside the then callback function, and use the return false; statement to break out of the loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {
    cy.get('#fndRow-' + (i - 1))
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .click();
  }
  cy.get('#fndRow-' + i)
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .click();
  cy.get('.infosArticleBtn')
    .click()
    .then(() => {
      cy.get('.infosArticleBtn').then(() => {
        cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
          if ($body.find('.detailArticle').length > 0) {
            cy.get('.detailArticle').click();
            return false; // break out of the loop
          }
          cy.log("article not found");
        });
      });
    });
}
```

If that works for you.!

Comment: unfortunatly it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

Due to asynchronous execution of Cypress commands, you cannot break the loop. But you can skip the iterations:

```js
let stop = false;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cy.then(() => {
   if (!stop) {
      if (i > 0) {
        cy.get('#fndRow-' + (i - 1))
          .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
          .click();
      }
      cy.get('#fndRow-' + i)
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .click();
      cy.get('.infosArticleBtn')
        .click()
        .then(() => {
          cy.get('.infosArticleBtn').then(() => {
            cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
              if ($body.find('.detailArticle').length > 0) {
                cy.get('.detailArticle').click();
                stop = true;
              }
              cy.log("article not found");
            });
          });
        });
     } // if (!stop)
  }); // cy.then
}
```

Notice the `cy.then` that wrap up the entire body of the loop.

Comment: you can vote up the answer then.

Comment: as a new member, I can't vote :(

Answer (score 0):

```
let articleFound = false;
for (let i = 0; i < 5 && !articleFound; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {
    cy.get('#fndRow-' + (i - 1))
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .click();
  }
  cy.get('#fndRow-' + i)
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .click();
  cy.get('.infosArticleBtn')
    .click()
    .then(() => {
      cy.get('.infosArticleBtn').then(() => {
        cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
          if ($body.find('.detailArticle').length > 0) {
            cy.get('.detailArticle').click();
            articleFound = true;
          } else {
            cy.log("article not found");
          }
        });
      });
    });
  if (articleFound) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cypress commands are asynchronous. All the iterations will be done before the execution get to the `then` callback with `articleFound = true`. 
So this code will not break the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Comparing to the previous answer, I propose to use **break** statement as **return false** exit the current function. If you use **break** statement, it will exit only the loop.Good luck!

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        cy.get('#fndRow-' + (i - 1))
          .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
          .click();
      }
      cy.get('#fndRow-' + i)
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .click();
      cy.get('.infosArticleBtn')
        .click()
        .then(() => {
          cy.get('.infosArticleBtn').then(() => {
            cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
              if ($body.find('.detailArticle).length > 0) {
                cy.get('.detailArticle').click();
                break;
              }
              cy.log("article not found");
            });
          });
        });
    }
```